# How to delete multiple rows in Jqgrid MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

My view is displayed by external javascript instead of in the view itself. How do i delete multiple rows in jqgrid? I have the `multiselect` and `multiboxonly`set equals to true. Here are my codes

View (the view is formatted in "~/Scripts/TodoList.js")

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>TodoList</h2>

<div>
<table id="grid"></table>
<div id="pager"
</div>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="m1">Get Selected id's</a>

<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
@*<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type ="text/javascript"></script>*@
<script src="~/Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/TodoList.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Todolist.js (Jqgrid)

```
/* File Created: February 17, 2017 */
$(function () {
    $("#grid").jqGrid({
        url: "/TodoList/GetTodoLists",
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'Get',       
        colNames: ['Id', 'Task Name', 'Task Description', 'Target Date', 'Severity', 'Task Status'],
        colModel: [
            { key: true, hidden: true, name: 'Id', index: 'Id', editable: true },
            { key: false, name: 'TaskName', index: 'TaskName', editable: true },
            { key: false, name: 'TaskDescription', index: 'TaskDescription', editable: true },
            {
                key: false, name: 'TargetDate', id: "elem", index: 'TargetDate', editable: true, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'd/m/Y' },
                editoptions: { dataInit: function (elem) { $(elem).datepicker(); } }
            },
            { key: false, name: 'Severity', index: 'Severity', editable: true, edittype: 'select', editoptions: { value: { 'L': 'Low', 'M': 'Medium', 'H': 'High'}} },
            { key: false, name: 'TaskStatus', index: 'TaskStatus', editable: true, edittype: 'select', editoptions: { value: { 'A': 'Active', 'I': 'InActive'}}}],
        pager: jQuery('#pager'),
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40],
        height: '100%',
        viewrecords: true,
        // Bug Codes
       //  loadonce:true, //compulsory for search        
        //cellEdit: true,         //inline edits
        //cellsubmit: 'clientArray', //inline edit
        caption: 'Todo List',
        sortname: 'id',
        sortorder: 'desc',
        multiselect: true,
        multiboxonly: true,
        emptyrecords: 'No records to display',
        jsonReader: {
            root: "rows",
            page: "page",
            total: "total",
            records: "records",
            repeatitems: false,
            Id: "0"
        },
        autowidth: true,        
    }).navGrid('#pager', { edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: true, refresh: true }, //search: true       
        {
            // edit options
            zIndex: 100,
            url: '/TodoList/Edit',
            closeOnEscape: true,
            closeAfterEdit: true,
            recreateForm: true,
            afterComplete: function (response) {
                if (response.responseText) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            }
        },
        {
            // add options
            zIndex: 100,
            url: "/TodoList/Create",
            closeOnEscape: true,
            closeAfterAdd: true,
            afterComplete: function (response) {
                if (response.responseText) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            }
        },
        {
            //delete options
            zIndex: 100,
            url: "/TodoList/Delete" + ,
            closeOnEscape: true,
            closeAfterDelete: true,
            recreateForm: true,
            msg: "Are you sure you want to delete this task?",
            afterComplete: function (response) {
                if (response.responseText) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            }
        });                  
});
```

Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data;
using TodoListApplication.DBContext;
using TodoListApplication.Models;

namespace TodoListApplication.Controllers
{
    public class TodoListController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /TodoList/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        TodoContext db = new TodoContext();
        public JsonResult GetTodoLists(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)  //Gets the todo Lists.
        {
            int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
            int pageSize = rows;
            var todoListsResults = db.TodoLists.Select(
                    a => new
                    {
                        a.Id,
                        a.Severity,
                        a.TargetDate,
                        a.TaskDescription,
                        a.TaskName,
                        a.TaskStatus
                    });
            int totalRecords = todoListsResults.Count();
            var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)rows);
            if (sord.ToUpper() == "DESC")
            {
                todoListsResults = todoListsResults.OrderByDescending(s => s.TaskName);
                todoListsResults = todoListsResults.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
            }
            else
            {
                todoListsResults = todoListsResults.OrderBy(s => s.TaskName);
                todoListsResults = todoListsResults.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
            }
            var jsonData = new
            {
                total = totalPages,
                page,
                records = totalRecords,
                rows = todoListsResults
            };
            return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        // TODO:insert a new row to the grid logic here
        [HttpPost]
        public string Create([Bind(Exclude = "Id")] TodoList objTodo)
        {
            string msg;
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.TodoLists.Add(objTodo);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    msg = "Saved Successfully";
                }
                else
                {
                    msg = "Validation data not successful";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                msg = "Error occured:" + ex.Message;
            }
            return msg;
        }
        public string Edit(TodoList objTodo)
        {
            string msg;
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.Entry(objTodo).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    msg = "Saved Successfully";
                }
                else
                {
                    msg = "Validation data not successfull";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                msg = "Error occured:" + ex.Message;
            }
            return msg;
        }      

        public string Delete(int Id)
        {
            TodoList todolist = db.TodoLists.Find(Id);
            db.TodoLists.Remove(todolist);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return "Deleted successfully";
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

jqGrid send comma-separated list of ids in case of deleting rows in `multiselect: true` mode. Thus you should change `string Delete(int Id)` to `void Delete(string id)`. The corresponding code could be about the following:

```cs
public void Delete(string id)
{
    var ids = id.Split(',');
    foreach (var id in ids) {
        TodoList todolist = db.TodoLists.Find(int.Parse(id));
        db.TodoLists.Remove(todolist);
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

I'd recommend you to consider too use `loadonce: true` option and to simplify your co return **all** items at once. It's the best scenario in case of displaying small number of rows (less as 1000 for example). It will simplify your server code and to improve the performance (responsibility) of the grid.

I'd recommend you additionally to verify that you use the latest version of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) (which you can download from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/free-jqGrid/) or to load directly from [CDN](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)). You should review jqGrid options, which you use and to remove unneeded or wrong options/parameters.

Comment: it says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". The troubleshoot tips suggest that i use the new keyword to create an object instance.

my jqgrid also at its latest version.

Comment: @Jesse: Is it the error, which you get in your C# code (server side code) or your JavaScript code (client side code). In which line of your code you get the error? Probably you need to rename `csvIds` parameter to `id` (see updated code of my answer)?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It was the C# code, and the output is still the name even if i have rename 'csvIds' to id.

I have also debugged the code, turns out the "string id" param receive no value...

Comment: Hi @Oleg, I have managed to solved my problem. It turns out that your method works, it's just the name of id that controller passes not tally with the id that i specify in my delete method parameter. Thank you very much! :) I will attach a detailed explanation in my answer.

Comment: @Jesse: You are welcome! I'm glad that the problem is solved now.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem, with the help by @Oleg codes.

1st: 
I found out that the id name that my controller uses to pass the id is "id", while my delete method in my controller says "Id" :

```
 public string Delete(int Id) // < see this
        {
            TodoList todolist = db.TodoLists.Find(Id);
            db.TodoLists.Remove(todolist);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return "Deleted successfully";
        }
```

[click here to see the debug result, pay attention to Form Data Section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hg6pt.png)

So there is a name mismatched between the id specified by controller and the id that i specified in my delete method

2nd:
So i modified my delete method in controller to become:

```
public ActionResult Delete(string id)
        {
            var ids = id.Split(',');
            foreach (var idsss in ids)
            {
                TodoList todolist = db.TodoLists.Find(int.Parse(idsss));
                db.TodoLists.Remove(todolist);
            }
            db.SaveChanges();

            var result = new { msg = "Deletion Successful ! " };
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Now it works now, thanks to @Oleg !